# ¿Como se entiende "go into real estate" en español?

Tags: traducción

Estuve leyendo un artículo en inglés y me encontré con esta frase. Según he buscado, `real estate` significa `bienes raíces`, pero traduciendo esta frase de manera literal a `irse a bienes raíces` no le encuentro sentido en español. ¿Alguien ha usado o sabe que significa esta expresión? Indico la oración en inglés (adaptada) donde lo encontré:

> Some of them were even thinking that perhaps they should have gone into real estate instead of enduring another one of these reviews.

Comment: Caramba, veo que eliminaste tu perfil en [es.so] :( Gracias por todo el trabajo que hiciste allí durante tanto tiempo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En relación a esa frase en particular, estoy de acuerdo con @EmilioGort, me suena a `meterse en el negocio del sector inmobiliario/bienes raíces`.

Aunque se necesitaría algo más de contexto, ya que la frase completa por sí no nos da un sentido completo, podría ser algo así:

> Some of them were even thinking that perhaps they should have gone into real estate instead of enduring another one of these reviews.

Traducción (aquí considero que review es una reunión de análisis, a las que, en algunos sitios, se les suele llamar con ese mismo nombre en español):

> Algunos de ellos habían incluso llegado a pensar que deberían haberse metido en el negocio del sector inmobiliario antes que aguantar otra de esas reviews.

Comment: No es correcto usar la palabra 'review' en la traducción en español porque esa palabra ni siquiera existe en el diccionario de la RAE.

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo. Al igual que @AliciaR. creo que sería mejor cambiar `reviews` por `revisiones` en la traducción, para lectores futuros.

Comment: Aunque no es recomendable por el DRAE creo que review se entenderia ya que su uso en el espanol es bastante generalizado por lo menos en los ambientes tecnicos en los que yo he estado involucrado

Answer (score 1):

Yo entiendo el `have gone into something` como adentrarse en algo, como lo diríamos en Cuba es `entrar/meterse en el negocio de bienes raíces`

Puede variar depende del contexto, no creo o no conozco que haya una traducción literal para esa frase.